# Anything was made for a reason

Tags: american-english, synonyms, british-english

Is there any particular term for this? "Anything has made for something (a reason)"

examples:
1- Computer invented for calculation
2- Sword has made for killing

A kind of general phrase to say that there was an absolute reason to making something new (invention) in the past.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't understand what you're asking.  Do you mean that some  other word should be substituted for "anything"?   Perhaps if you gave a real example sentence.

Comment: One term that comes to mind is *ungrammatical*

Comment: _has_ is the past tense of the verb _to have_.  I think you want _was_ (past tense of the verb to be).  In which case, are you asking for a term that indicates that there was a reason for the item being created?

Comment: Yeah absolutely just is there any saying in English for that? I will edit question again

Comment: "Anything" should be "everything".  anything has negative polarity.

Comment: The sentences might be called "statements of purpose".  But, from a pure semantic point of view they are simply "assertions".

Comment: You can say, [Everything has a purpose](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=everything+has+a+purpose&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ceverything%20has%20a%20purpose%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Necessity is the mother of invention."  (English language proverb)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the word you are looking for is ***purposeful***?

> ***[Purposeful](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/purposeful)***
>
> ADJECTIVE
>
> 1. Having or showing determination or resolve.
>      *‘the purposeful stride of a great barrister’*
> 2. Having a useful purpose.
>      *‘purposeful activities’*
> 3. Intentional.
>      *‘if his sudden death was not accidental, it must have been purposeful’*

I think definitions 2 & 3 are relevant.

Comment: My emphasis is on invention reason on the past :|

Comment: "SHOULD NOT REINVENT THE WHEEL" I mean another proverb that have this meaning

Comment: I can't think of any such idioms, other than, perhaps _everything for a reason_ which is a common bit of nonsense that means that whatever happens, it happens for a reason (because, presumably, god has decided that.)

Comment: @RogerSinasohn "everything for a reason" has such a "mystical" idiomatic sense to it that I don't believe it is what the OP is looking for.  Of course, the OP question is so poorly written it might include that "destiny" sense even though his examples really don't

Comment: @Tom22 -- I agree but I thought I'd throw it out there just in case.

Answer (score 1):

I might suggest "**derived for**" or, possibly "***devised for***"

Note,  the most idiomatic use of "derive" is "derive from" not "for" and the definitions for the word "derive" alone more closely relate use with "from"

"for" would mean purpose while using "derived" assures a reference to the source concept, action or topic

> [***Derive*** at Websters-Merriam](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/derive)
>
> verb (used with object), derived, deriving.
>
> 1.
>   to receive or obtain from a source or origin (usually followed by from).

and then of course "for"

> [***for*** from Merriam-Webster](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/derive)
>
> 1.
>   with the object or purpose of:
>   to run for exercise.
>
> 2.
>   intended to belong to, or be used in connection with: equipment for the army;
>   a closet for dishes.
>
> 3.
>   suiting the purposes or needs of:

Or the second alternative starter word:

> [***Devise*** from Websters-Merriam](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/devise?s=t)
>
> 1.
>   to contrive, plan, or elaborate; invent from existing principles or ideas:
>   to devise a method.